# Multiple inheriting classes with different scoped properties

Tags: kotlin

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do just isn't possible or if I'm just thinking about this completely wrong but what I'm trying to do is essentially this. I have a sealed class with multiple classes within like this:

```
sealed class MySealedClass(val thing: Thing) : MyPropertyInterface
{
    val name: String = thing.name

    /** Base Methods Here */

    /** Obj 1 Constructor */
    class ObjOne(thing: Thing) : MySealedClass(thing)
    {
        override val properties = PropertyTypeOne()
        override val otherProperties = PropertyTypeTwo()

        inner class PropertyTypeOne(){
            val one = 1
        }

        inner class PropertyTypeTwo(){
            val two = 2
        }
    }

    /** Obj 2 Constructor */
    class ObjTwo(thing: Thing) : MySealedClass(thing)
    {
        override val properties = PropertyTypeOne()
        override val otherProperties = PropertyTypeTwo()

        inner class PropertyTypeOne(){
            val one = 1
        }

        inner class PropertyTypeTwo(){
            val two = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I want the classes within my sealed class to inherit these scoped properties in the way an interface would to force them to initialize them since they will contain the same type of properties but different values. The reason I want the properties to be scoped is because rather than accessing them through a list I want to access them directly (simply for more readability) and without the scoping it could become unclear what you're accessing. I realize that I could create a custom interface for each class inside the sealed class containing said classes with said properties, but my issue there is that I want to, in a way, enforce this as a rule upon the classes within the sealed class that they must construct these two data structures. By creating a custom interface per class it would then be possible that one of them no longer fits the criteria due to human error.

Comment: Yes, you may define an interface, and implement it both for ObjOne and ObjTwo. Also a shorter syntax possible - val property = object : TypeName { ...}

Comment: If I create an interface that has a property with type Any and then instance it as an object and then instance my properties inside there then they are inaccessible when I instance the class within the sealed class. E.g. val newObj = ObjOne(); newObj.properties.(compiler will not know what custom properties were instanced)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have come to to obtain my desired result:

```
sealed class MySealedClass(val p0: Int, val p1: Int) : MyProperties{

    /** Base properties and methods */

    class MyClassA(p0: Int, p1: Int) : MySealedClass(p0, p1){
        override val propertyListOne: MyProperties.PropertiesA = MyProperties.PropertiesA()
        override val propertyListTwo: MyProperties.PropertiesB = MyProperties.PropertiesB()
    }

    class MyClassB(p0: Int, p1: Int) : MySealedClass(p0, p1){
        override val propertyListOne: MyProperties.PropertiesC = MyProperties.PropertiesC()
        override val propertyListTwo: MyProperties.PropertiesD = MyProperties.PropertiesD()
    }
}

interface MyProperties{
    val propertyListOne: Any
    val propertyListTwo: Any

    class PropertiesA{
        val one = 1
    }

    class PropertiesB{
        val two = 2
    }

    class PropertiesC{
        val three = 3
    }

    class PropertiesD{
        val four = 4
    }
}

fun testMethod(){
    val newClassA = MyClassA(0, 0)
    newClassA.propertyListOne.one
    newClassA.propertyListTwo.two
    val newClassB = MyClassB(0, 0)
    newClassB.propertyListOne.three
    newClassB.propertyListTwo.four
}
```

I realize that all of this could be done easier by just simply creating lists but I specifically am not looking to index these values. Also this structure makes the hierarchy of the object structures of the code I'm working on much easier to understand and read.